# Javascript является синхронным или асинхронным языком программирования?

Tags: javascript

Обыскал множество сайтов и ресурсов, нигде не сказано определение. Я думаю, что так Javascript всегда является синхронным однопоточным языком, но мы можем сделать Javascript асинхронным с помощью программирования. Или js сразу асинхронный язык?

Comment: а вы поищите мб найдете там среди описания синтаксиса `async/await`

Comment: пишут, что всегда синхронный где асинхронный не знаю, как правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js работает в одном потоке и является синхронным. Асинхронность добивается с помощью коллбеков. В современном синтаксисе существуют промисы и async/await - это обертка над коллбэками. Чтобы понять суть работы, вам нужно изучить работу event loop. От себя советую посмотреть этот ролик https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ

Также хорошие материалы для изучения:

https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks

https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-basics

https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await